# Is the a.out executable format still in use?

Tags: linux, executable

I'm sure that in light of the [recent deprecation of the a.out format on Linux](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/deprecating-aout-binaries) quite a few people have heard about the ancient executable format.

I'm creating a loader for the format just in case someone still uses it, but I need to test my loader to make sure it works.

Are there any projects still using the a.out executable format? Is there any benefit to still using it?

Comment: If you need old i386 a.out binaries from 1995, here you are: http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian-0.93R6/binary/base/ . For example it wouldn't make sense to support (only) amd64 a.out, because when it appeared, a.out was already a thing of the past. Maybe some other archs took longer (and there's the OSF/1 thing in your link)

Comment: @A.B I don't think amd64 a.out ever worked, as the a.out.h header file defines some pointer types as "int".

Comment: @A.B Um... Those .deb files aren't in the AR format.

Comment: Dang you are right. I dearchived it with dpkg but didn't check ar. It might be "that" older .deb format. Format is described there: https://manpages.debian.org/dpkg-dev/deb-old.5

Comment: Ok I made a script example: `mkdir -p dest/DEBIAN; cd dest/DEBIAN; cat ../../sed-2.05-4.deb | ( read dummy; read size; dd bs=$size count=1 | tar -xzvf -; cd .. ; tar -xzvf -); cd ..`   . You're now in dest with unarchived sed package (and control files in DEBIAN)

Comment: @A.B I'm just building dpkg-1.0.0 (and patching it as I go along).